# Any trick to re-write in vector form $\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln(1 + \eta_i x_i) $, where $x, \eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry, for a stupid question probably.

Is there any trick to re-write this in vector form $$\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln(1 + \eta_i x_i) $$ where $x, \eta \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

---

Comment: By vector form you mean $\eta$ and $x$ appear in the formula as "whole" vectors instead of the components $\eta_i$ and $x_i$? Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am trying to do some matrix calculus (or gradients in vector form) rather than in index form per se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{i=1}^n -\ln(1 + \eta_i x_i) \equiv -e^T \ln(e + x \odot \eta )$, where $e$ is all-ones vector